# Translation of "I'm planning to do that next week"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate

> I'm planning to do that next week

I'm thinking

> Ich habe vor, das nächste Woche zu machen.

Does it sound strange to put "das" after the comma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's perfect. It's actually a quite common mistake among native speakers to misspell the *das* as *dass* in a situation like this. But no, it doesn't sound strange at all.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's not wrong but I'd say it sounds a bit stiff.

The sentence may be affected by the previous one as the context could determine which part of the sentence should get more focus.

Take a look at these examples

> Das plane ich, nächste Woche zu machen. *(focus on action, you may not be sure if you will get around to it)*
>   Nächste Woche habe ich vor, das zu machen. *(focus on time when talking about several future plans)*
>   Das nehme ich mir nächste Woche vor. *(action focus, more natural and a tiny bit ambitious)*

Comment: In my opinion, all of your example sentences are worse than the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The translation is fine but it feels a bit clunky to me. I think I would leave out the whole machen-part all together because it doesn't add any information. It is just grammatical filler.

> Ich habe mir das für nächte Woche vorgenommen.
>
> Das steht nächste Woche an/auf dem Plan/auf meiner Agenda.

Or the more straight forward way using "wollen"

> Das will/wollte ich nächste Woche machen.

Note, that the use of past in this situation does not mean that you don't plan that anymore. There is the same phrasing in English.

> The dishes? Oh I was planning on doing those next week.

Comment: Or simply: Das mache ich nächste Woche.